# NSCollectionView crash when layout out of frame

Tags: objective-c, macos

Firstly, the collection view can't scroll.

Secondly, when scroll, crashed.

Showed that "array out bounds"..

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[PreviewImageItem class] forItemWithIdentifier:[PreviewImageItem reuseIdentifier]];
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

    self.collectionView.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.collectionView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.collectionView.layer.borderColor = NSColor.redColor.CGColor;
    self.collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.collectionView setNeedsLayout:YES];
    [self.collectionView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
```

and delegate method :

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PreviewImageItem *item = [collectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:[PreviewImageItem reuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"111 %ld", indexPath.item);
    return item;
}
```

crash on:

```
2018-09-02 14:40:15.840071+0800 sishi[50265:6062453] 111 50
2018-09-02 14:40:15.840677+0800 sishi[50265:6062453] 111 51
2018-09-02 14:40:15.841271+0800 sishi[50265:6062453] 111 52
2018-09-02 14:40:15.841866+0800 sishi[50265:6062453] 111 53
```

[View for collectionview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qdpp.jpg)

I'm just want create a colleciton view to show some pictures. It crazy me today..

Who can tell me how to create collectionview.

Both Using xib or only code are fine. Thanks!

Comment: As I checked, there is no problem with the code in your question. Could you tell us which line of code causes crash?

Comment: no line code. Just crash at main() method and no logs for the crash..

Comment: You said that `Showed that "array out bounds"` and now no logs for crash. Can you make it clearer?

Comment: @user5611145: the crash is not in main(). You just don't know how to debug a macOS app. You need to set an exception breakpoint. How to do this is explained (for example) [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2943-my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) (it's a tutorial for iOS, but most of it applies to macOS too.)